# RTC DS3231 headache

Tags: rtc, feather

I've been trying to get an RTC clock to display time. I tried using 3 different RTC modules: standard ds1307, pcf8523 and ds3231.

They all give the same results: wrong time and no incrementing. It does not matter if I manually insert a timestamp or if it gets it at compile time.

I am using using a Feather Adalogger and an MPU6050 accelerometer. The battery is good and the connections have been verified. It's as if there is some value in some memory somewhere that reverts to the timestamp below.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <Wire.h>

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

char t[32];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__),F(__TIME__)));
  //rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  sprintf(t, "%02d:%02d:%02d %02d/%02d/%02d",  now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second(), now.day(), now.month(), now.year());  
  Serial.print(F("Date/Time: "));
  Serial.println(t);

  delay(1000);
}
```

Here's the printout:

```
Date/Time: 00:35:00 04/00/2020   
Date/Time: 00:35:01 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:02 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:03 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:00 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:01 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:00 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:01 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:02 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:03 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:00 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:01 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:02 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:03 04/00/2020  
Date/Time: 00:35:00 04/00/2020
```

Comment: Ok so its really an I2C issue. How dos I wire multiple I2C devices on feather adalogger?

Comment: The output you've shown makes it look like the board is resetting.  It would be more clear if you had something distinct printing in `setup()`.

Comment: Are you resetting the board repeatedly? Your `setup()` function always resets the date/time to the time the sketch was built.

Comment: Normally, in a situation like this... you create a sketch that will initialize and SET the current time for the RTC.  After that, you create a new sketch that only initializes and reads the RTC for your actual clock functions thus keeping the two actions  (SET/GET) isolated.

Comment: did you run I2C scanner?

Comment: How may I2C devices do you have connected? And what are those? It might be an I2C address conflict.